# Issues with Installing libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.3)

Tags: dependencies, filezilla

I was trying to install filezilla but this dependency(libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.3)) was missing. On trying to install the dependency from the source, I was unsuccessful. Can someone please advise on how to fix it. 
And when installing the dependency I was able to configure it, make it but the make install did not go through.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 filezilla : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.3) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
```

Result from 'sudo apt-install -f'

```
sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Package: filezilla
Version: 3.25.1-1~getdeb1
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: GetDeb Package Ninjas <package.ninjas@getdeb.net>
Installed-Size: 6,748 kB
Depends: filezilla-common (= 3.25.1-1~getdeb1), libc6 (>= 2.17), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libfilezilla0 (>= 0.9.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.3), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.10.0), libnettle6, libpugixml1v5 (>= 1.7), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg), libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg)
Recommends: xdg-utils
Homepage: https://filezilla-project.org/
Download-Size: 1,768 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu yakkety-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Description: Full-featured graphical FTP/FTPS/SFTP client
 FileZilla is a full-featured FTP client with an easy-to-use GUI.
 .
 It is written in C++ and uses the wxWidgets library.
 .
 FileZilla includes the following features:
   * Supports FTP, FTP over SSL/TLS (FTPS) and SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)
   * IPv6 support
   * Available in more than 40 languages
   * Supports resume and transfer of large files >4GB
   * Easy to use Site Manager and transfer queue
   * Bookmarks
   * Drag & drop support
   * Speed limits
   * Filename filters
   * Directory comparison
   * Network configuration wizard
   * Remote file editing
   * Keep-alive
   * HTTP/1.1, SOCKS5 and FTP Proxy support
   * Logging to file
   * Synchronized directory browsing
   * Remote file search
   * Tabbed interface to connect to multiple servers

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt install -f` and append the results of that command to your question?

Comment: Thank you.  Can you also post the output of `sudo apt-mark showhold`

Comment: Nothing happens when I give that command.

Comment: K - this next one asks for a lot more data to be posted.  Please execute `apt show filezilla` and post all of the output to your question.

Comment: Added to the question. Please take a look

Comment: Ok...  Are you running Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes I am running 16.04. Let me check the difference between yakkety and xenial.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running a mix of repositories for Xenial (16.04) and Yakkety (16.10).  In particular, your system wants to install version 3.4.10 of libgnutls30, which is from the Xenial archives, but the version of FileZilla you are trying to download (3.25.1) is from a Yakkety archive and requires a newer version of libgnutls.

You should examine your sources and determine which version of Ubuntu you are really running (Yakkety is end-of-life) and set the sources in a manner appropriate for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps and install filezilla -**

Open "Software and Updates" and click the "Other Software" tab. Now look for duplicate entries in the list of ppas that have checkmarks besides them. Uncheck all entries that are related to the getdeb ppa. Enter your password when required.

When you are done, click Close. A box will pop up telling you that you need to refresh the software sources. Click the Reload button. If you get errors at this point, something is still wrong with the list of ppas. Go back and fix the list.

Once you have completed this part of the task, you need to remove any software that actually got installed from these ppas, if any. For the sake of brevity, I will assume that none did.

Now that your list of software sources is fixed, you can install Filezilla using sudo apt install filezilla

If your system is more messed up than I assumed, come back and edit your question to include any additional error messages that you received.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it should do the task. I will let you know how it goes.